# perl script to search for sql statement from a file with keywords

Tags: perl

I am trying to search in a .sql file for sql statement which starts with **CREATE TABLE** followed by fields values then keywords [**TB_DATA and TB_INDX**] and ends by **;**

Like

```
CREATE TABLE HDTB_CODE (IDPK VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL) IN TB_DATA INDEX IN TB_INDX;
```

**.sql file** statement is in multiple lines

```
CREATE TABLE HDTB_CODE
(
IDPK VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL
)
IN TB_DATA
INDEX IN TB_INDX;

--CREATE TABLE HDTB_BYTE
(
RTID VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL
)
IN TB_DATA
INDEX IN TB_INDX;
DROP TABLE HDTB_BYTE;
CREATE TABLE HDTB_RES
(
ARTID VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL
)
IN TB_DATA
INDEX IN TB_INDX;
CREATE TABLE HDTB_DE
(
IDPK VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL
);

-------------output----------------------

CREATE TABLE HDTB_CODE
(
IDPK VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL
)
IN TB_DATA
INDEX IN TB_INDX;

CREATE TABLE HDTB_RES
(
ARTID VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL
)
IN TB_DATA
INDEX IN TB_INDX;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = 'somefile.sql';
open(my $fh, '<', $filename) || die "unable to open '$filename' for read; $!";

local $/ = "";     # Paragraph mode
while (<$fh>) {
    if (/^CREATE TABLE.+TB_DATA.+TB_INDX/s) {
        print   # or do something else
    }
}

close $fh;
```

The use of an empty string in `$/` marks "paragraph mode", which means the record separator is two (or more) new-lines, so it breaks on the blank lines (if that is not the case, then you could use ";\n").

The `s` modifier after the regular expression is required for `.` to match new-lines.

Comment: what if there is no newline. how to use it as Paragraph mode

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I have been away.  If there is no newline then pick something else for the record seperator.  `$/` can be set to just about anything, paragraph mode is just a convienient short-cut (comes from awk).

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

$/ = '';
print grep { $_ =~ /CREATE TABLE/ && $_ =~ /INDEX/} <>;
```

Or:

```
$/ = '';
print grep { /^CREATE TABLE.+TB_DATA.+TB_INDX/s} <>;
```

Usage:

script_name.pl sql_file

Comment: Not without the `s` modifier.

Comment: It is splited into two regex, so it works. One regex will indeed need the `s` modifier.I added a second option though, with your nice regex :)